# Creating multiple copies using overloaded '*' operator

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

The thing I'm trying to do is use the multiplication operator to create multiple copy instance of an object.

I.e.

```
myclass instance;
instance * 5;
```

would create 5 copies of instance. So I am using an object array to create these instances.

```
cube* operator* (int i, const cube& thing) {
        cube* objectarr = new cube[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            objectarr[i] = thing;
        }
        std::cout << i << " number of copies created\n";
        return objectarr;
    }
```

But I get an error saying "too many parameters for this function". 
However, if I make it a friend function then it can take more than one argument.
Problem arises when I try to execute an example.

```
#include <iostream>

#define TB '\t'
struct cube {
    int height;
    int width;
    int bredth;
    cube() {
        height = 0;
        width = 0;
        bredth = 0;
    }
    cube(int i, int j, int k) {
        height = i;
        width = j;
        bredth = k;
    }
    cube operator+=(const cube& c);
    friend cube* operator* (int i, const cube& thing) {
        cube* objectarr = new cube[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            objectarr[i] = thing;
        }

        std::cout << i << " number of copies created\n";
        return objectarr;
    }
};

int main() {
    cube c1(10, 20, 30);
    cube* mptr = new cube;
    mptr = 4 * c1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        std::cout << mptr[i].height << TB << mptr[i].width << TB << mptr[i].bredth << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is this.

```
4 number of copies created
0       0       0
0       0       0
0       0       0
0       0       0
```

I want to know

**1.** Why is this happening?

**2.** Why can the multiplication operator not take more than one argument, except when its a friend function(I've searched it online but understood little of it)?

Thank you

Comment: FWIW overloading operators to do something they would not do for a built in types is not something you should do.  Instead a named function whose name specifies what it will do should be used.

Comment: Also 
cube* mptr = new cube;
  mptr = 4 * c1; 

isn't going to do what thing it does - I think you should consider using smart pointers + vectors.

Comment: @UKMonkey ` 
Also cube* mptr = new cube; mptr = 4 * c1; isn't going to do what you want it to do ` , why?

Comment: mptr = new cube :  allocates memory and calls default constructor;
mptr = XXX : memory leak

Answer (score 0):

1. this is operator abuse, just use the copy constructor.
2. `instance * 5` is not the same as `5 * instance`.  You've got the latter.

Comment: In the definition, int precedes object , `friend cube* operator* (int i, const cube& thing);`  and in `main()` too I'm using `4 * c1` , not `c1 * 4`

Answer (score 0):

No can do I'm afraid.

You are not allowed to change the *arity* of an operator when overloading it. This means you can't adjust the number of arguments.

The `friend` function to which you are referring would relate to a version of the overloaded multiplication operator for your particular class at "outside the class" scope: so it *would* take 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather use design patterns' factory to create multiple instances of your class.

The '*' operator is not intended to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the overload is a member, `*this` is the operator's left-hand side and there's only one explicit parameter.
If you want the left-hand argument to be something other than your class, you must make the overload a free function.

For example, if you have

```
struct A
{
     int operator *(int x) { return x * y; } 
     int y;
};

int operator*(int x, A a) { return a.y * x }


A a{2};
```

then

```
int z = a * 2;
```

calls `a.operator*(2)`, while

```
int w = 2 * a;
```

calls `operator*(2, a)`.

A better implementation of your particular operator would be

```
std::vector<cube> operator* (int i, const cube& thing) 
{
    return std::vector<cube>(i, thing);
}
```

or if you want symmetry:

```
struct cube
{
   // ...
   std::vector<cube> operator*(int i) const { return std::vector<cube>(i, *this); }
};

std::vector<cube> operator* (int i, const cube& thing) 
{
    return thing * i;
}
```